# XML Validation in Eclipse - Confirming Local XML File Validates against Remote Namespaces

Tags: xml, eclipse, xml-namespaces

I have an XML file I created manually and I wanted to validate it's structure. The XML file references the namespaces that contain the schemas the XML file structure must honor (I need to obscure a bit, but essentially it looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF8"?>

<can:Candidate xmlns:can="urn:mars:crater:v1:candidate" xmlns:guy="urn:mars:crater:v1:dude" xmlns:artfct="urn:mars:crater:v1:Artifact" xmlns:ci="urn:mars:crater:v1:Info" xmlns:f="urn:mars:crater:v1:file" xmlns:gen="urn:mars:crater:v1">
<can:candidateVersion>1.0.1</can:candidateVersion>
<can:Object>
<can:Name>Bob</can:Name>
<guy:Person>
  <guy:Identity identityId="512">
    <guy:Collection>
      <guy:Name>
        <guy:WithLove>
          <String>Object</String>
        </guy:WithLove>
        <guy:Duh>
          <String>Full</String>
        </guy:Duh>
        <guy:mode>
          <String>M</String>
        </guy:mode>
      </guy:Name>
    </guy:Collection>
    <guy:BirthDate exact="true">
      <DateTime>Wed Aug 28 00:00:00 EDT 1974</DateTime>
    </guy:BirthDate>
  </guy:Identity>
</guy:Person>
<artfct:Artifact>
  <artfct:Type>
    <Value code="2147">SIZE</Value>
    <Srr id="1" value="SIZE" code="2147" gen:genus="U"/>
  </artfct:Type>
  <artfct:Uniquer>
    <String>210</String>
    <Srr id="1" value="210" gen:genus="U"/>
  </artfct:Uniquer>
</artfct:Artifact>
</can:Object>
</can:candidate>
```

When I validate from eclipse, I get a single warning: **"No grammar constraints (DTD or XML Schema) referenced in the document"**. I am surprised that my manually-created xml file successfully validated without more errors against the namespace information. Is it possible I am not actually validating against those namespaces? How do I ensure that I am?

Thank you.

Comment: You need to actually reference a schema (XSD file), not just the namespace.  E.g. see some examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336370/xsd-validation-in-eclipse-no-grammar-constraints-warning)

Comment: Thanks Scott. So.. put another way, if the xml header only references namespaces, the xml can't be validated since the corresponding schemas are missing (validating = schemas + namespaces). Correct?

Comment: Sorry, my comment was too quick and probably misleading.  The XSD has to be supplied somewhere but a nice way to do it and avoid cluttering your XML with references to locations (which you don't want to hard code) is through an XML Catalog which you can easily set up in Eclipse.   Will answer below.

Comment: I was just trying to say that "no, you are not actually validating anything" which is what the warning message is telling you.  The XSD has to be supplied somehow / somewhere.   But not, actually it doesn't have to be via a `schemaLocation` in the XML.  A nice way to do it is through an XML Catalog (see [here](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/XMLValidation/XMLValidationTutorial.html) and [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Using_the_XML_Catalog).    E.g. you can add a user-defined catalog entry w/ a local schemaLocation and a "Key type" of `Namespace name`. Hope that helps.